# GNUCash Fund management fees

Tags: gnucash

how can I create a transaction against a fund to reflect ongoing fund management fees?  This will be a percentage of my investment that is deducted annually.

It seems to me the only way to do this currently is to create a transaction to sell, then another to buy and add on an investment fee but this seems really convoluted.

Comment: How are you currently increasing or decreasing the account value based on market changes when you haven't sold? Do you have an "Investment Gain/Loss" account or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I have it set up as a fund which allows me to update the prices in exactly the same way as stocks and shares, when I purchased the units I set a split and in the investment expenses entered a transaction fee from my platform. This shows as a broker fee when I run an advanced report. I tried setting up a transaction to an investment expenses sub account and the options are provide shares, buy or sell but no matter what I enter this throws off my figures. The only option I can see so far is setting up a transaction to sell everything, buy it again and enter a platform fee but this looks wild when I run a report.